# Configuring Plesk panel on Google Compute Engine

Tags: centos, plesk, google-compute-engine, controlpanel

I am trying to configure Plesk panel on Compute Engine running CentOS.I am very new to all this, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question! After the install, I can't access my Plesk panel. I understood from the documentation that I could access it by navigating to *myipaddress:8443*. This does not access any web page. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you double-check that the network your instance belongs to allows TCP traffic on port 8443?

Comment: @Adrián Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From the developers console, click on your application that has the google compute engine instance installed on it.

2) Click on Compute (left menu)

3) Click on Networks (left menu)

4) Click on the default IP at the top of the page

5) Under firewall rules, click new

6) In the popup enter a name (i.e. open my ports)

7) In PROTOCOLS & PORTS enter `tcp:8443`

8) Save and you're done!

Note: If you want to add extra ports, like ftp access, enter `tcp:8443,21`

Comment: I think I'm heading in the right direction now! :) But I still can't access Plesk at myipaddress:8443 I should be able to log in to my Plesk panel from here, am I correct?

Comment: @Maverick you're a pioneer, I don't think many people are using plesk on this, it may not run correctly without customizations to it because of the modified Centos image on GAE. I tried installing cPanel but it won't run on it and they don't offer any support to get it running. I have successfully gotten ispconfig and webmin running.. If you are just trying to host sites you administer, I recommend webmin, if you are trying to offer hosting services then ISPconfig, but I could not get FTP to work with it, but I did not try real hard

Comment: Would I be better off with hosting on DigitalOcean?

Comment: " may not run correctly without customizations to it because of the modified Centos image on GAE."  I am actually using Compute Engine, not App Engine. Is the Compute Engine version of CentOS modified also?

Comment: @Maverick I meant GCE. I don't know what digitalocean is, but at Rackspace cloud I have had no problem setting up Cpanel,have not tried plesk there

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @Maverick No problem, if my past headaches can save you some time, glad to help. By the way forgot to answer the question about modified version of Centos... I just mean they modify the images to work in their environment, like adding and removing some things, for example SSH as root.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia I'm trying to do the same thing as Clayton Decker. Plesk is installed and although I already added the port number to the firewall. I still can't acces Plesk on my GCE ip. The strange thing is that when I added the port to the firewall, 8443 direct me to: https://servername:8443. It does not stays at http://myipaddress:8443. Why?